# How to use Angular8 project inside my main angular project?

Tags: angularjs, angular, node-modules

I have one situation come where i have two projects one is in AngularJS which is main project and one is in angular 8. Now, i want to import Angular8 project inside angularJS Project.

Can any one suggest me better way for this?How can i overcome from this problem?

Comment: You can't. AngularJS uses javascript meawhile Angular2 onwards uses typescript. Both are syntactically different.

Comment: @ShreyashSolanke I might be wrong to giving details but yet ts ultimately convert into js at the time of compilation. it is just to connect two application most likely on data flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible way to start using A8 components/services etc. in an existing AngularJS project is ngUpgrade. [Here is](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) a detailed step-by-step explanation. 
With ngUpgrade module you can `downgrade` an existing Angular component

```
angular.module('heroApp', [])
  .directive(
    'componentNameInAngularJS',
    downgradeComponent({ component: ModernAngularComponent }) as angular.IDirectiveFactory
  );
```

But you probably (I'm not sure, it depends on existing code base) should give up A8 routing and let AngularJS control the flow, until you completely replace all AngularJS components with modern Angular. You should consider such an option, cuz` AngularJS official support ends in 2021.